# What should be the ip and port for connecting redis-cluster?

Tags: node.js, redis, cluster-analysis, scaling, redis-cluster

I have one situation to deal with redis-cluster.Actually we want to move to redis-cluster for high availability.So, currently we have one transaction server and we are using redis for managing mini-Statements.We have single instance of redis running on default port with 0.0.0.0 ip. In my transaction server, i have one configuration file in which i am putting redis ip and port for connection.

My Question:

1) Suppose i have two machine with redis server and i want something like if one machine died then my transaction server will automatically use second machine for its work and it should have all the keys available.So for this what ip and port i should configure in my transaction server config file and what should be the setup for redis to achieve this goal?

A suggestion or a link will be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looking for high availability solution for Redis, you might want to look inot Redis Sentinel but not cluster.
Redis Sentinel offers exactly what you need, you can see the official [document](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel) for more information.